# How can I get the color scheme of a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to get the color scheme, for example RGB or CMYK, of an image in a `UIImageView`. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by color scheme? Please provide further details to your question..

Comment: Voting to reopen. What the OP is asking is clear (enough). I also edited it before it was closed. My answer should help others understand what image property the OP is asking about (its Color Model).

Comment: @justin it is clear enough also, that OP doesnt show **any** effort to solve this problem

Comment: @justin but I agree that put it on hold with "unclear what you're asking" is a wrong reason

Comment: @MikroDel Oops. The OP's effort was mentioned in the initial question -- I scrubbed that when I edited the question to improve the question's SNR.

Comment: @justin "I've try to search this in iOS documents, but without a result." its not an effort in meaning of this site. Its true that it is easier to close queition, that try to improve it and thats why many users dont like it :)

Comment: @justin with such an effort "I've try to search" you can post in any crap queistion and no need to show your code examples

Comment: @MikroDel sure, searching the docs doesn't mean much in general. in this case, the property in question was 4 degrees of separation from the source -- which is distant enough (IMO). anyways, lots of room to be subjective here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *simple case*, you can access the color model by accessing the `UIImageView > .image > .CGImage > ColorSpace > Model`.

```
// briefly illustrating the common path, with no error checking:
UIImageView * imageView = ...;
UIImage * image = imageView.image;
CGImageRef cgImage = image.CGImage;
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage);
CGColorSpaceModel model = CGColorSpaceGetModel(space);

if (kCGColorSpaceModelRGB == model) {
  ...
}
else if (kCGColorSpaceModelCMYK == model) {
  ...
```

The `UIImageView` itself merely presents/renders an image. `UIImage`s can be backed by different sources (e.g. `CGImage` or `CIImage`), and they can represent many different data/image types. Depending on your images, your implementation may need to support additional cases.